# Getting console output of mac os app without using xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging

I am able to debug iOS apps on other machine without using xcode (even on windows) by using the iPhone Configuration Utility tool from Apple. More info here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1747/_index.html

But for macos apps, I cannot find a similar tool for debugging apps on a non-developer mac. I am new to this and would appreciate some help from experienced developers how is this typically done on real world.

Comment: That link seems to show how to get the crash log, which isn't debugging is it.

Comment: If you will go to the "Getting Console Output Without Xcode" section, that is what I meant to say

Comment: Please update your question; debugging implies running the app under a debugger, setting breakpoints etc.  Getting the crash logs is nothing like that.

Comment: True, I didn't realized that it was confusing until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get console output and crashlogs for os x applications from the console app.

You'll find it inside the Utility folder of your Applications folder. Or simply open spotlight and type "console"